# How to group after 2 columns and count data?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, distinct

I have table in database:

`uid` bigint(12) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

`bike_name` int(10) NOT NULL,

`start_time` datetime NOT NULL,

`end_time` datetime NOT NULL,

`start_place_id` int(10) NOT NULL,

`end_place_id` int(10) NOT NULL,

`cust_id` int(10) NOT NULL, - customer_id

And i want to group in select query by: year and month: distinct DATE_FORMAT(`start_time`,'%Y-%m') as `time` and get how much difrent customers get bike in this month.

For example:

2016-05, 1200 (1200 diffrent cust_id),

2017-05, 3600 etc..